# Isekai manga, main character has the ability to transfer soul to another body

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I once read an isekai manga where the main character fights the bandit girl to revenge his companion that she killed. When the main character wins he transfers his companion soul to the body of the bandit girl.

Comment: This is quite brief can you remember anything else that you could [edit] in? For example, when did you read this?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: If shufly has the correct answer, you can accept it by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for [Dorei Shounin shika Sentakushi ga Nai desu yo? Harem? Nani Sore Oishii no?](https://mangadex.org/title/31583/dorei-shounin-shika-sentakushi-ga-nai-desu-yo-harem-nani-sore-oishii-no)

The exchange in question is in chapter 6. The main character fights a bandit lady who had killed his friend. The friend is following him as a ghost. Once he wins he casts a spell to remove the bandit lady's soul from her body, then he shoves his friend's ghost into it.

The only thing i'm seeing that doesn't match is that it isn't an isekai.